# You must select a host application to run a commands only target? Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm running my code and it compiles fine with no errors, and used to send an output to the terminal, however it now gives me a prompt saying `You must select a host application to "run" a commands only target`.

I don't know what I've done, and I have never come across this before. Has anyone any ideas how to select the correct host application?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a million.

Here's a `test.cc` file code that I'm trying to run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <TrajectoryDSGenerator.hh>
#include <DSAdjust.hh>

int
main()
{
    // REAL THING!!
  // Initial conditions
  uu::Vector x0(2);
  x0.set(0, 5.0);
  x0.set(1, 10.0);
  // Real Parameter
  uu::Vector P(4);
  P.set(0, 2);
  P.set(1, 20);
  P.set(2, x0[0]);
  P.set(3, x0[1]);

  uu::TrajectoryDSGenerator ds(2, 4);
  ds.setParameters(P);

  // Where to compute the trajectory
  uu::TrajectoryDSGenerator::TimeStamps T;
  T = ds.generateTimeStamps(0.0, 10.0, 0.1);

  // Generate the sample trajectory at the given timestamps
  uu::VectorTrajectory Tr(2);
  uu::TimedVector xic(0.0, x0);
  Tr = ds.generate(xic, T);
  // Store the sample trajectory
  std::ofstream ofd;
  ofd.open("sample.traj");
  ofd << Tr;
  ofd.close();
  std::cout << "Trajectory Saved" << std::endl;





  // Now read the sample trajectory from the file
  std::ifstream ifd;
  uu::VectorTrajectory iTr(2);
  ifd.open("sample.traj");
  ifd >> iTr;
  ifd.close();
  std::cout << "Trajectory Loaded" << std::endl;

  // Vector with the initial guess of the parameters
  uu::Vector P0(4);
  P0.set(0, 10);
  P0.set(1, 5);
  P0.set(2, 20);
  P0.set(3, 2);
  //  P0 = P;
  //P0.set(0, 5);
  uu::TrajectoryDSGenerator ods(2, 4);
  uu::DSAdjust adj(&ods, P0);
  std::cout << "Added sample trajectory" << std::endl;
  adj.addSampleTrajectory(iTr);

  std::cout << "Optimising" <<std::endl;

  uu::Vector Pf(adj.optimise()); // Learnt parameters from the real trajectory (thing)
                                // This improves your initial guess of the parameters

  std::cout << "Real Parameters: " << P;
  std::cout << "Initial guess: " << P0;
  std::cout << "Learnt Parameters: " << Pf;

   // Generate a trajectory with the learnt parameters
  ds.setParameters(Pf);
  uu::VectorTrajectory TrPf(2);
  x0.set(0, Pf[2]);
  x0.set(1, Pf[3]);
  uu::TimedVector xic1(0.0, x0);
  TrPf = ds.generate(xic1, T);

  // Store the trajectory with the improved guess of the parameters
  ofd.open("result.traj");
  ofd << TrPf;
  ofd.close();
  std::cout << "Trajectory Saved" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, include the chunck of code that you are testing, and the best analysis you can do about what you expect it to do, the error, and where it occurs. Thank you, and welcome to SO. :)

Comment: Thanks @canolucas, I've edited my above question to show the test code I'm trying to run. Basically it is split up into 3 main parts, an initial trajectory, a guess at trajectory, and then it uses optimization function to create a more accurate version of the guess parameters. So I want it to basically show the values to the command line. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 8):

The same thing happened to me. To fix this:

- Go to Project->Properties

[image: Step 1]

- Go to the Build Targets tab

[image: Step 2]

- Change the "Type" drop-down box to "Console Application"

[image: Step 3]

- (Optional) Check the box "Pause when execution ends" if you don't want the terminal window to instantly close when it pops up

[image: Step 4]

- Click the "...", select the output file that you want to run, and click "Save". If a box pops up asking about replacing the file, replace it.

[image: Step 5]

Problem solved!

Comment: Could this be automated in CMakeLists.txt, perhaps?

Comment: @AngeloGeels Maybe. I wouldn't know; I hate CMake. ;)

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to the "Project" tab on top

2- Select "Properties"

3- Select "Build Targets" tab
4- Select "Debug" on the left

5- Next to "Type: ", select whatever you want exept "Commands Only". If you don't know what to choose select "GUI" (for a hidden application) or "Console" (for a console window application)

6- Select "Release" on the left

7- Repeat step 5